# MySQL 5.7.16 shows no Product Configuration option during installation on Windows 10

Tags: mysql

I am trying to install MySQL v.5.7.16 along with the Workbench and Connectors.

All installation videos/tutorials show a Product Configuration step during installation. However, when I use the installer I never receive a Production Configuration step. I show a screenshot below. The Product Configuration should appear below the Installation step in the blue left-hand side menu as shown in the second picture. [image][image]

Answer (score 8):

I went through the same problem as well. What I did to fix it was simple:

1. Reopening the file, "MySQL Installer.exe"
2. You'll see the list of product you've installed. At the column "Quick Action," you'll see a word, "Reconfigure."
3. Hit it! Done!

Answer (score 5):

Steps:

1. Uninstall MySQL products from your machine.
2. Delete "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL" folder.
3. Go to "https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/8.0.html".
4. There are two options for "**Windows (x86, 32-bit), MSI Installer**", choose "(mysql-installer-**community**-8.0.22.0.msi)" version, instead of "(mysql-installer-**web-community**-8.0.22.0.msi)". The *community* installer is an offline installer, while *web-community* is an online installer.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. This worked well for me.

open the installer again from the start menu and click reconfigure.

I found reconfigure option for 3 of the installed items.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 reason. iF mysql is not running

1. Your port 3306 was already in use
2. Your password is not set.
   To resolve both issue please use the follwoing steps:
   Step1: Uninstall Workbench as well as mysql installer (Sometime you already have workbenche but not mysql installer so Uninstall both)
   Step2: Download Mysql Installer again
   Visit http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/
   Step3: While installing this change PORT 3306 to 3308 or whatever you want
   Step4: Set Password and install all the depenedencies again.

If you Forgot the password click on Windows search mysql installer and reconfigure the password. Try now
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I successfully installed the SQL Community Server installer for 5.6.34. I made no changes to my firewall, etc.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/5.6.html

MySQL may have a problem with the latest 5.7 installer, or I had a corrupted install that mostly worked but would not configure.

A few lessons learned:

- The Product Configuration should appear as an option immediately
  after selecting to install a specific version of SQL Server (x86 or x64) in the SQL Installer UI.
- If anyone else has this problem, I suggest uninstalling the installer the first time you see this problem.

Comment: To the anonymous user who downvoted this: I found a bug and reported it here. Please do not remain anonymous and explain why you downvoted this bug reporting. Can you explain why I see this bug?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following steps helpful:

1. relaunch your MySQL installer,
2. go to "my server" and reconfigure it,
3. set the root password

.. and it's done!